# trying to do a python for code without using the "in" operator and it's not working

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Simple assignment from uni, supposed to find a word in a list and print if true without using the "in" operator. I've instead used = and it's just not printing anything. Is there something wrong with the code or is there an alternative I'm missing?

```
wordlist = ["hi", "many","way","photo","mobile"] 

def word_in_list_for(words,word):
    for word = wordlist:
        if word == wordlist:
            return True
        else:
            continue
print(word_in_list_for(wordlist,"bild"))
```

Comment: thank you so much!! knew i was missing something but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_in_wordlist(words, word):
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):
        if words[i] == word:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False
```

Testing:

```
In [221]: wordlist = ["hi", "many","way","photo","mobile"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [222]: print(word_in_wordlist(wordlist,"bild"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
False

In [223]: print(word_in_wordlist(wordlist,"photo"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
True
```

Comment: thank you! the assignment specifies that we need to use for loops, but this helps with the previous part where i need to use the while loop!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```py
wordlist = ["hi", "many","way","photo","mobile"] 

def word_in_list_for(words,word):
    i = 0
    while wordlist[i]:
        if word == wordlist[i]:
            return True
        else:
            i += 1
print(word_in_list_for(wordlist,"bild"))
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: thank you! this works for my previous assignment, but for the one i asked about they specified that we must use a for loop!

Comment: @Saga I understand but it impossible to have a for loop in python without using `in`... Sorry! Maybe look at this answer but it doesn't use a for loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034142/14983900

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`

```py
wordlist = ["hi", "many","way","photo","mobile"] 

def word_in_list_for(words,word):
    words_set = set(words)
    return {word}.issubset(words_set)
print(word_in_list_for(wordlist,"bild"))
```

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the indexing. I have written an working example from your code. You can find the explanation as comments in script.

**Code:**

```
wordlist = ["hi", "many", "way", "photo", "mobile"]


def word_in_list_for(words, word):
    for index in range(len(words)):  # Get the indexes of your list.
        if word == words[index]:  # If the value of the index is the same as word
            return True  # Return True
    return False  # The the elem is not is the list return False


print(word_in_list_for(wordlist, "bild"))
```

**Successful test (`word_in_list_for(wordlist, "mobile")`) :**

```
>>> python3 test.py
True
```

**Unsuccessful test (`word_in_list_for(wordlist, "bild")`) :**

```
>>> python3 test.py
False
```